# ¿Como detectar el estado de la tecla mayusculas cuando un componente de React es recargado?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Necesito leer el estado de la tecla bloqMayus cuando un componente de react es recargado.
Hasta el momento, solo puedo leer el estado de la tecla cuando la misma es presionada, pero si la tecla esta activa y recargo la pagina, el estado de la tecla mayusculas no es reconocido.

Answer (score 2):

No lo puedes detectar en cualquier momento, sino cuando hay algún evento de entrada de datos (un click o movimiento del ratón, una tecla pulsada...). En ese caso puedes comprobar en el objeto evento los modificadores activos:

```js
function isCapsLockOn(event) {
  const caps = event.getModifierState && event.getModifierState('CapsLock');
  console.log('¿Está el bloqueo de mayúsculas activado?', caps);
}

document.addEventListener('mouseenter',isCapsLockOn);
document.addEventListener('keydown',isCapsLockOn);
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Por ejemplo lo podrías comprobar cuando el puntero del ratón está sobre tu componente.

**Nota**: Presionar la tecla <kbd>BloqMays</kbd> lanza el evento, pero **antes** de que el bloqueo se active, por eso te mostrará `false` al activarla y `true` al desactivarla